# First child css NEW

Tags: html, css

Please tell me why first-child does not work. NEW

How can I set styles for the first child element of `.all`?

Necessarily!!!!

I don't know the exact index of the desired element.

Necessarily!!!!

```css
#one {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid;
  font-size: 0px;
}

#one #two {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}

#one .all {
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
  display: inline-block;
}

#one .all:first-child(1) {
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">
  <div id="two"></div>
  <div class="all"></div>
  <div class="all"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe [read the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child) as to how `:first-child` works

Comment: Why doesn’t it work? Because the element is not the first child, and `:first-child()` doesn’t exist; I can only assume you got confused with `:nth-last-child()`.

Answer (score 2):

The following syntax is invalid.

```css
#one .all:first-child(1) {}
```

You might be looking for `:nth-child()` and got confused as `:first-child` doesn't take any parameters or arguments.

To solve your problem, you might need to use `:nth-of-type()` and need to give the index as `2` because this is the second element matching this type:

```css
#one {
  width: 500px;
  height: 250px;
  border: 1px solid;
  font-size: 0px;
}

#one #two {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: blue;
}

#one .all {
  width: 250px;
  height: 200px;
  background: green;
  display: inline-block;
}

#one .all:nth-of-type(2) {
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">
  <div id="two"></div>
  <div class="all"></div>
  <div class="all"></div>
</div>
```

**Preview**

[image: preview]

Comment: `:nth-of-type` is meant to be used with an element, not a class. There's no `:nth-of-class` though, so `#one :nth-of-type(2)` and `#one div:nth-of-type(2)` would work

Comment: I don't know the index because there could be a large number of other elements before the desired element.

Comment: @Vector Lemme think of alternate solution. But there's only JavaScript / jQuery solution possible.